# 'pipenv install <package>' fails on fresh python3.10 installation

Tags: python, pip, debian-based, python-3.10

Just installed a fresh copy of Python3.10 via Pop OS, followed by pip and the python Pipenv package. Installing pip packages works fine globally, but if I try to use pip inside a virtual environment on its own (for *any* package, Numpy to name one) I get:

From running `pipenv install <package>` from outside my venv in the project folder,

```
Installing numpy...
Error:  An error occurred while installing numpy!
Error text: 
/home/xxxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/xx-xxxxx-Kg4m1CDN/bin/python: No module named pip

✘ Installation Failed
```

and from `pip install <package>` from inside the venv,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/xx-xxxxx-Kg4m1CDN/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

version details:

`python3.10 --version`: Python 3.10.0b1

`python3.10 -m pip -V`: pip 21.3.1 from /home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

(specific names x-ed out for privacy)

I've already googled around and checked the Pipenv GitHub so I'm stumped. Hopefully this is something simple that I've so far managed to avoid but I have no idea where to go from here - any help would be appreciated!

If there are any other logs or any info needed just let me know.

Comment: What does `python3.10 -m pipenv --version` show?

Comment: `pipenv, version 2021.11.23`

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with the same issue also. And the only solution for me is to install Python 3.9 in addition.

You can download from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3912/

After installing the Python 3.9.12 (don't forget to tick the "Add Python to PATH" checkbox), the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get your python3.10, pip3 with python version 3.10 and virtualenv installed, And you try to create the environment, but you get issues with pip packages, I found that after updating the python and pip, I still had old pip installations, so I updated all the existing older version pip packages using,

`pip3 list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U`

And thus I was able to create a virtual environment.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install pip again in the env.
Refer to the links below:-

```
[a link] <https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/>
[a link] <https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-in-linux/>
[a link] <https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-in-macos/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: apt-getting pip won't do anything, and using the get-pip script didn't help either - can you give me any specifics? Not sure what you mean by installing it again, unless you mean somehow passing the env to the installer?